# Animating a CCMenuItem in Cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I created this code below to show a button in the view in init statement:

```
    CCMenuItem *contacts = [CCMenuItemImage 
                            itemFromNormalImage:@"play.png" selectedImage:@"play.png" 
                            target:self selector:@selector(switchcontact)];
    contacts.position = ccp(300, 550);
    CCMenu *starMenu6 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:contacts, nil];
    starMenu6.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:starMenu6];
```

I need to rotate or animate this button in the view in same position, just like the Fruitninjas menu button.
How could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with the fruit ninja method but to rotate the contacts menu button do:

```
[contacts runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:.5 angle:45]]];
```

You could do it on the menu as well, they're both CCNodes.